# PySpark: How to deal with wrong scale in DecimalType (trailing zeroes)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have parquet data that I read with spark and write out to csv. For some reason, the information about precision and scale in columnA is wrong. It should be (29,**0**), I get (38,**9**). As a result, I receive user_ids like this: 341234134.**000000000** instead of this: 341234134.

Is there any way, other than an explicit schema provided to the script, to deal with this scenario and avoid these 0s? I am looking for a generic solution that can be applied to many tables/columns, so doing a transformation on the exact column doesn't really do anything.

I have tried using format_number and similar, but it basically rounds my numbers and I cannot have that - because in some columns there may be actual decimal numbers that I don't want to lose.

Thanks

Comment: in sql cast(col as number(29,0))

Comment: you could cast your column to the desired precision

Comment: i could cast the column, but it is not a generic solution that would fit other tables and columns - so it doesnt solve my problem @leftjoin

Comment: you cannot have spark guess if you want bigdecimal or a bigint - you must tell it, either per leftjoin you use cast, or as you wrote in the question use a schema - those _are_ the generic ways.  There may be something else that can be done for your actual use case but as your question is written the only options are the ones you have rejected.

Comment: A good first step would be to find out why _"For some reason, the information about precision and scale in columnA is wrong."_ Because Spark WILL format a decimal(29,0) exactly as you want, without decimal point and 0-padding.